# backbone-pageable, when I deleted the last row of page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backgrid

I am using this code for remove a row

```
$(document).on("click",
"#deleteSelection${cadenaAleatoria}",
function(){

$('.alertaGrillaResultado').css('display','inherit');
 var selectedModels = grid.getSelectedModels();

 if(selectedModels != ''){
_.each(selectedModels, function (model) {
  model.trigger("backgrid:select", model, false);
  var id = grid.collection.fullCollection.where({ id: model.id });
  grid.removeRow(id);
  $.get("@{delete()}/" + model.id, function (modelos) {
  });
  $('.alertaGrillaResultado').html(
        '<div class="alert alert-success">' + '<button type="button" class="close"      data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>' + "Se retiro el Tipo de Eventualidad seleccionada" + '</div>'
    );
});
collection.fetch({reset:true});



  }
```

$('.alertaGrillaResultado').fadeOut(3000);
     });

but when I delete the last row of one page 
I get this error:

throw new RangeError("`currentPage` must be firstPage <= currentPage " +
                               (firstPage ? ">" : ">=") +
                               " totalPages if " + firstPage + "-based. Got " +
                               currentPage + '.');

how to update pagination? how to resolve this?

Comment: What exactly are u doing? Why are you deleting via jQuery instead of Backbone? Why are you fetching from 2 URLs into the same collection twice and is collection the same as grid.collection?

Comment: collection.fetch({url: 'tipoeventualidades/listavacia/',reset:true});
collection.fetch({url: 'tipoeventualidades/lista/',reset:true}); i correct this collection.fetch({url: 'tipoeventualidades/listavacia/',reset:true});
collection.fetch({reset:true});

Comment: My problem is when I page have only one item and I deleted it I get the error  throw new RangeError. for example I have 4 pages and the last one (4) has 1 item

Comment: What's your pageable's initial state?

Comment: also which versions of the libraries are u using? there used to be a bug related to this many months ago.

Comment: backgridjs i am  using v0.2.* and few days ago I update the  backbone-pageable

Comment: I am using this collection.getLastPage(); and it works